# Maximum hyperrectangle

Tags: geometry, optimization

Is there a way to determine the coordinates of the maximum hyper-rectangle in n-D space subject to linear constraints and $x_i\ge0$ ?

Example:

Argument Maximum of $x_1 x_2 x_3$

Given

$x_1+3x_2+5x_3=20$

$x_1+x_3=10$

$x_i\ge0$

Yields $\{8.83796, 1.78395, 1.16204\}$

Is there a way to solve the problem in general, given $AX=B$ as constraint?

(It might be the case that if $d$ of the $x_i$ are required to be zero, then the hyper-rectangle is optimized in (n-d)-D space)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your conditions to eliminate variables.  We want to maximize $x_1x_2x_3$.  The second condition gives $x_1=10-x_3$, then the second gives $3x_2+4x+3=10, x_2=\frac 13(10-4x_3)$, so we are maximizing $(10-x_3)(10-4x_3)x_3$.  Take the derivative, set to zero, solve for $x_3$

Comment: Yes, that was an illustrative small example which can be solved directly. I was wondering how to solve it in the general case of AX=B. Is there a trick using eigenvalues or determinants, etc?